# Access passed attribute value in visualforce component constructor

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a visualforce component, that takes in an attribute of account ID. Now this attribute in the component is assigned to a variable in the component's controller. In the constructor of the component's controller, I have put the value of this variable in system.debug and it is being shown as null.

But when I later invoke the same code by a button on the component which invokes a method in the component's controller - the value is shown correctly in the debug log. Hence concluded that in the component's controller constructor cannot obtain the value in the getter/setter field.

Is there any way to achieve this, i.e. obtain a value passed from the VF page into the VF component, in the constructor of the VF component? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, check this question - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9941/setter-method-in-vf-component-being-called-after-the-constructor-has-retured

Comment: Yes first your controller called then all assignTo executes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kurunve already indicated: this has to to with the order of execution for visualforce pages. First the constructor is executed and only after that the expressions in your component are executed.

See hereunder a chart of th Visualforce execution life cycle.

[image: VisualForce Order of Execution chart]